# Looping through folder to generate and save graph for each file

Tags: stata, stata-macros

Below is one of my `csv` files created from `dataex` for a reproducible example:

```
clear

input str32 eventname str10 scrapedate float(average thpercentile v5 v6)
"EventName" "2015-12-15"  136.9255     83.2 104.875    148.75
"EventName" "2015-12-16"  130.4555    78.55      99    138.22
"EventName" "2015-12-17" 123.66705     72.7   90.25     131.2
"EventName" "2015-12-18" 116.45757   64.855   78.55     119.5
"EventName" "2015-12-19" 108.63446 60.56333    72.7 119.07333
"EventName" "2015-12-20"  94.97125    55.15   69.77    112.48
end
```

Thanks to the answer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51401079/loop-for-changing-date-format-and-generating-graphs), I was able to adapt my code to loop through the directory `"I:\Games CSVs\"` and  read in each `csv` file using:

```
insheet using "`file'", comma clear
```

Then create a new variable to change the data format to how I want it and generate the line graph.

Here is my code:

```
local foodir "I:\Games CSVs\" 
local files : dir "`foodir'" files "*.csv"
cd "`foodir'"
local i = 0
foreach file of local files {
    local ++i
    insheet using "`file'", comma clear
    generate ScrapeDate = daily(scrapedate, "YMD")
    format ScrapeDate %tdYY-NN-DD 
    line average thpercentile v5 v6 ScrapeDate, name("graph`i'", replace) ///
    scale(*.7) ///
    local filename = substr("`file'", 1, strlen("`file'")-4) ///
    title(filename) ///
    ytitle("Price in US$") ///
    legend(size(small)) 
}
```

The problematic line is the following:

```
local filename = substr("`file'", 1, strlen("`file'")-4)` 
title(filename)
```

I also tried:

```
generate filename = substr("`file'", 1, strlen("`file'")-4)` 
title(filename)
```

I have the following problems:

1. The file is being titled as `filename.csv` and I want the suffix to be removed.
2. I also cannot figure out how to save the graphs on disk.

All the graphs (I have 52 of them) are flashing one after another. It would be ideal for me, if I could save all of them in a folder (`I:\Graphs`), with `filename` being the same as the `filename.csv` instead here being saved as `filename.png` or `filename.jpeg` or whatever format that I will be able to open.

I have read the documentation. I believe `graph save mygraph` replaces the graph if it exists, and since I'm looping through the directory, each time, the graph is going to be replaced since I'm not changing the name of the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *correctly* define the local macro `filename` before you use it. You also need to use the `saving()` and `nodraw` options in the `line` command:

```
local foodir "I:\Games CSVs\"
local foosavedir "I:\Graphs\"

local files : dir "`foodir'" files "*.csv"
cd "`foodir'"

local i = 0
foreach file of local files {
    local ++i
    insheet using "`file'", comma clear
    generate ScrapeDate = daily(scrapedate, "YMD")
    format ScrapeDate %tdYY-NN-DD 
    local filename = substr("`file'", 1, strrpos("`file'", ".")-1)
    line average thpercentile v5 v6 ScrapeDate, name("graph`i'", replace) ///
    saving("`foosavedir'`filename'.gph", replace) nodraw scale(*.7) title("`filename'") /// 
    ytitle("Price in US$") legend(size(small)) 
}
```

Note that in this way, the files will be saved in Stata's `gph` native format, which is always the best thing to do so you can edit them later if necessary.

If you also want them in a different graphics format such as `png`, then you need to export each of them after the `line` command:

```
graph export "`foosavedir'`filename'.png", name("graph`i'")
```

In this case, you must **not** have specified the `nodraw` option in `line`.

The graphs will be replaced if the option `replace` is specified, and the name of the saved/exported file conflicts with an existing file. If the filenames are unique you shouldn't have this problem.